# Access ContractFactory in web3-react

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, ethers.js, web3-react

I'm using `web3-react@^5.0.5` to interact with web3 from my react app. I can connect to metamask just fine.

I set the library to `ethers.js` and connected to metmask. Connecting worked fine, but almost none of ethers.js's methods are there. For example, `useWeb3Context().library.ContractFactory` doesn't exist.

Is this normal?

#### Code

Root component:

```
  ...
  return (
    <Web3Provider connectors={connectors} libraryName="ethers.js">
      ...
    </Web3Provider>
  );
  ...
```

`connectors` object:

```js
const { InjectedConnector } = Connectors;

// Initially support Ropsten and Mainnet
const MetaMask = new InjectedConnector({ supportedNetworks: [1, 3] });

export const connectors = { MetaMask };
```

Subcomonent:

```js
function SubComponent() {
  const web3 = useWeb3Context();

  function connect() { /* Connect to MetaMask, works fine */ }

  async function deployContract() {
    // Fails:
    // TypeError: web3.library.ContractFactory is not a constructor
    const factory = new web3.library.ContractFactory(ABI, BINARY);
  }

  return (/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: An example of integrating `web3-react` and `ethers.js` was done here: https://github.com/Uniswap/interface